# Cannot create a list of lm objects in R

Tags: r

I am creating a list of 20 `lm` objects such that the degree of the polynomial corresponds to the position in the list.

I have the first `lm` object with a response `y` and a predictor `poly(x, degree = 1)`, the second would be with response `y` and predictor `poly(x, degree = 2)`, and so on till `poly(x, degree = 20)`. The following is the code I wrote:

```
model_list = list()
for(deg in 1:20){
   model_list[[deg]] = lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = deg), data = data)
}
```

Now I'm trying to apply a function to all the objects in `model_list` that calculates the RMSE of each `lm` object like so:

```
rmse = sapply(model_list, rmse_function, data = data2, response = "y")
```

and I keep getting an error:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object 
lengthError: variable 'poly(x, degree = deg)' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "nmatrix.20" was supplied
```

I tried straight creating 20 different lm objects and then making a list out of them, and the `sapply` works there, but not on this list from the for loop.

I tried using `lapply` and that does not change the issue, and looking up previous posts it seems to be something with setting `degree = deg`, but I'm not sure how to change it so that the `sapply` works.

EDIT:
The `rmse_function` is as follows:

```
rmse_function = function(model, data, response){
  sqrt(mean((data[, response] - predict(model, data)) ^ 2))
}
```

`data` and `data2` are just data frames from reading csv's of 2 columns (`x` and `y`) with randomly generated numbers in the range of (-10,10) for both columns.

Comment: you don't give us nor `data` nor `rmse_function`...

Comment: data2 and data are the same ?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited that when I saw I forgot to mention that!

Comment: I think your problem is with the predict function... try changing it just to `predict(model)` if you are using it on the same data... or `model[["fitted.values"]]`

Comment: The data being used with `predict` is actually different from the data being used in the model.

Comment: still I think it's the place to look, and be careful the newdata is the correct format

Comment: The thing is, that if I list out the lm models and store them in a list, then there is no problem. It's only if I create the list by using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you directly supply the formula into `lm()`, so inside your fitted model it will store the call `... poly(x, degree = deg)`. This call is later used inside `predict()`, and since `deg` is `20`, it will always create `nmatrix.20`. However, in `model_list` each fitted model has `nmatrix.N`, where `N` is the degree. Therefore, you get an error.

The easiest way to fix this, is to just create a string beforehand, and then transforming it to a formula inside `lm()`:

```
for(deg in 1:20){
   form <- paste0("y ~ poly(x, degree = ", deg, ")")
   model_list[[deg]] <- lm(as.formula(form), data = data)
}
```